# A biliographic inquiry into Fredholm's kernel

Tags: reference-request, math-history, trace, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I would like to get the exact bibliographic references from the paper(s) by Erik Ivar Fredholm in which the definition(s) of kernel and trace first appear.

If someone could even copy the extract from the text, it would be great.

Best regards, and thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics (Kernel)](http://jeff560.tripod.com/k.html) : "Ivar Fredholm used the French word, “noyau,” in his famous paper on INTEGRAL EQUATIONS, “Sur une classe des équations fonctionnelles,” Acta Math., 27, (1903), 365–390."

Comment: See Ivar Fredholm,  [Sur une classe d’équations fonctionnelles (1903)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485882170). Maybe I'm wrong, but I cannot find "noyau" in it...

Comment: And how about the word trace? Did he use it at some point?

Comment: For sure we have : I.Fredholm, [Sur une équation intégrale à noyau analytique (1925)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485887576).

Comment: Maybe the source is I.Fredholm, Sur une nonvelle methode pour la resolution du probleme de Dirichlet (1900).

Comment: [Kern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kern_(Algebra)) was used by David Hilbert : [Grundzuge einer allgemeinen theorie der linearen integralgleichungen (1904)](https://books.google.it/books?id=caARAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) and [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)) by Maxime Bocher, [An Introduction to the Study of Integral Equations (1909)](https://books.google.it/books?id=UbSwBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA13), referring to Hilbert and Fredholm.

Comment: For *trace* see [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics : Trace](http://jeff560.tripod.com/t.html).

Comment: So Fredholm never used the term trace then?